# CASE WHEN with same field

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table that contains few columns (see attached) for layout.

Now as you can see record 1 and 3 have same **"closing ECL"**.. What i want is which ever has highest **"TOTAL"** keeps the ECL amount and the other record(which had same total) **"Closing ECL"** gets updated to 0..

how do i do this? Very confused..[image]

**Scenarios:** 
[image]

Comment: post the sample output

Comment: Please add table structures and data as text in your question. Not image. Also add your query if you have tried something to do it. And expected output too

Comment: @mohan111 scenarios posted in post

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `update`:

```
update t
    set closingECL = 0
    where total < (select max(t2.total)
                   from t t2
                   where t2.primary_elf_id = t.primary_elf_id and
                         t2.closingECL = t.closingECL
                  );
```

This assumes that the logic is applied per `primary_elf_id`.

Note:  If the maximum `total` is duplicated, then all the maximuma remain.

Comment: so this is joining itself and checking which total is higher and setting the lowest to 0?

Comment: @Laura . . . That is a pretty good description of what it is doing.